# UserDetailsService embed in the Spring-Security configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring project, I usually ad this class to provide control access:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

  @Autowired
  private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf()
        .disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/signin")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
        .usernameParameter("login")
        .passwordParameter("senha")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
        .and()
      .rememberMe()
        .key("remember-me")
        .and()
      .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);

    web
      .expressionHandler(handler);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return auth.getOrBuild();
  }
}
```

Normally, I implement the beans  UserDetailsService, PasswordEncoder and PermissionEvaluator using separated class. Now, I am looking for a way to implement this beans inside the above class, as inner classes or methods.

Anyone knows if this is possible, and could provide me a link with an example of this?

Comment: Have you tried? Have you hit any specific problem?

Comment: Question is why would you want to bundle up the code? it makes it more difficult to debug, you can hit constraints/conflicts and readibility goes out the window